# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable - sigmoid gradient

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am getting error in ds = s(1 - s). Please suggest me what is the issue here

in sigmoid_derivative(x)
     16     ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)

```
 17     s = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

---> 18     ds = s(1 - s)

```
 19     ### END CODE HERE ###

 20 
 21     x = np.array([1, 2, 3])

 22     print ("sigmoid_derivative(x) = " + str(sigmoid_derivative(x)))
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: change line 18 to  `s*(1 - s)` or `np,dot( s,(1 - s))`

Answer (score 1):

Same error two questions in a row.
Is 's' a function or variable in your case?
May be you mean ds = s * (1 - s)?